# Trying to cater to past users on my blog

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to cater to past users who have posted in the past. What I am trying to do is highlight any of the users pasts posts and also, on the home page do something like welcome back $name ! ONLY if the user has posted before though. I have no idea how to do this, need to check against the database probably but I am not sure how.

Thank you in advance.

The blogs form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 150 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[-\.a-zA-Z\s0-9]{3,150}$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "message".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // "name" pattern : at least 1 digit

    value = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/\d+/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "name".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> <u>Daily Dorm News</u> <br> The best place to get your latest Dorm news </h1>
<form action="posting_wall.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="20" required><br>

Post:<br>

<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name='message'></textarea>
</div>
Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" required> <br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p><a href="posting_wall.php">Posting Wall</a></p>
<?php 

$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
// 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'The time at which you are posting is:'. date('h:i:s Y-m-d') ."\n";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Post page PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/post.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Your Daily Dorm News Post! </h1>
<div id="container"> <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php if ( isset($_GET['message']) and preg_match("/^[-\.a-zA-Z\s0-9]+$/", $_GET['message']) ) {

    echo $_GET['message'];

} else {

    echo "The message is not valid! The message box was blank or you entered invalid symbols!\n";

}
?>

This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>


</div>

<?php
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
* Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
*/

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);
$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
 // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  

 // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
 $post_fields = array();
 $post_fields['name'] = $name;
 $post_fields['email'] = $email;
 $post_fields['message'] = $message;
 $post_fields['date'] = $date;
 $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);

}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

require('header.php');
?>


   <p><a href="../index.php">Submit a Post</a></p>

   <?php
   if(isset($name)) {
     echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
   }
   ?>

   <p>Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
   <ul id="posts_list">
   <div id="posts">
   <?php

   // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
   $counter = 1;

   foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
     $name = $post['name'];
     $email = $post['email'];
     $message = $post['message'];
     $date = $post['date'];

     if ($counter % 2==1)
       $li_class = "float-left";
     else
       $li_class = "float-right";


        echo '<div class=post>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This event occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';

        echo '</div>';
   }
   ?>

   </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to record those users who have posted earlier in a mysql database..

Comment: i do have a datebase final called posts.dat, but how do I check to see if the user has posted before? what code would i use